Using add_rewrite_rule to redirect to page for a CPT
I'm looking to add 4 subpages for each "emplacement" custom post type on my WordPress site. The URL format I want to achieve is https://url.com/emplacements/emplacementslug/landingpage/.
Currently, https://url.com/emplacements/emplacementslug/ is working fine and returns the custom post type template.
I've created a custom Elementor template using the page with the ID 200.
Here's the code I'm using to add the rewrite rule:
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^emplacements/([^/]+)/landingpage/?$', 'index.php?emplacement=$matches[1]&page_id=200', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');

However, this isn't working as expected. It still returns the emplacement custom post type content, even when I disable the emplacement Elementor template.
How can I achieve the desired behavior?

add_rewrite_rule('^emplacements/([^/]+)/landingpage/?$', 'index.php?page_id=200', 'top') ?
